# Run process from .NET Core on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, .net-mac

I'm trying to run a process from C# console app on Mac:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("./gradlew", "bundleRelease")
{
    WorkingDirectory = gradlewDir,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};

var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

It fails with "no such file or directory" error. However if I run:

`var files = Directory.GetFiles(gradlewDir);` I do see this file in there. I also made sure all permissions are set to run it. I'm able to run it from the terminal too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably you need to fully qualify the path to `gradlew`.

Comment: @John I think you're right. Question for you, how do I pass parameters to it? I think I've passed the not found error, now I need to pass `bundleRelease` parameter and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: See the `Arguments` property :)

Comment: lol, that's what I do and it doesn't work :)

Comment: Ok got it. Even though I provide full path, I still need to set working directory for the process. May be specific to what I'm trying to do but anyways, you can post your answer and get credit for it ;) thank you @John

Comment: It sounds like you figured out the second half so I think you should add your full solution and I'll upvote it :D